# Get value between two strings or characters with spaces in it

Tags: regex, powershell

Hi I created a simple PowerShell script to analyze the fragmentation level of a volume for monitoring:

```
cd /
$c1 = defrag c: -a | findstr 'fragmented'
$c1.split('=')[1].trim()
```

The result I get is either `0%` or `10%` that is with single digit or double digits. What I would like is a regex command to get just the numeric value. I could still add another split command for % but was hoping a regex could do this without having multiple splits

Please note without the split command the original result looks like this with spaces at beginning and after the equals sign.

```
        Total fragmented space      = 0%
```

Comment: Don't run external programs & parse text output when there are objects & methods built in that will do the work for you.  Have a look at https://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/15/use-powershell-to-determine-fragmentation-of-your-drive.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: @alroc thanks, I just had a look and that would probably be a much better approach to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$fragmentation = (defrag c: /a) -match '%$' -replace '.*= (\d)%$','$1'
```

The `-match` operation restricts the output to just the lines ending with a `%` and the `-replace` operation extracts the numeric value from those lines. Since the line stating the fragmentation level is the only line with a percent value, the result is the numeric value of the fragmentation.

I have to agree with @alroc, though: using WMI is a better solution to your problem.

Comment: perfect that's what i actually needed and its also going to help with other scripts I am working on rather than asking any further questions.

Comment: Yes I also agree with him. I had also seen that but even the result will also need to be trimmed

Answer (score 1):

A regex solution might look like this:

```
$text = '10%'
$text -replace '(\d{1,2})%','$1'

10
```

But honestly, that's over complicated for what's required.  You can easily modify your existing script to also trim off the % like this:

```
$c1.split('=')[1].trim(' %')
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply strip the last character from what you got:

```
SET pct=$c1.split('=')[1].trim()
echo %pct:~0,-1%
```

Comment: Set-Variable : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '0%'.

Comment: That is a crude mixture of CMD and PowerShell syntax, which won't produce the desired result in either of those interpreters.